# Почему картинка под менюшкой?

Tags: html, css

Проблема в том, что картинка под меню (справа, желтым цветом), а должна быть справа от меню

```css
.right_menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.profile_photo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 390px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container_1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1"></div>
<div class="right_menu">
  <p>Моя страница</p>
  <p>Новости</p>
  <p>Сообщения</p>
  <p>Друзья</p>
  <p>Группы</p>
  <p>Фотографии</p>
  <p>Музыка</p>
  <p>Видео</p>
  <p>Игры</p>
</div>
<div class="profile_photo">
  <img src="PLANKTON.jpg" style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 2):

Изменённые строки помечены `!!!`:

```css
.right_menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
  float: left; /* !!! */
}

.profile_photo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 390px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
  margin-left: 220px; /* !!! */
}

.container_1 {
  /* display: flex; */ /* !!! */
}
```

```html
<div class="container_1"></div>
<div class="right_menu">
  <p>Моя страница</p>
  <p>Новости</p>
  <p>Сообщения</p>
  <p>Друзья</p>
  <p>Группы</p>
  <p>Фотографии</p>
  <p>Музыка</p>
  <p>Видео</p>
  <p>Игры</p>
</div>
<div class="profile_photo">
  <img src="PLANKTON.jpg" style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

Лучше обернуть все это в контейнер и использовать `display: flex;`

```css
.container {
  display: flex;
}

.right_menu {
  width: 150px;
  height: 400px;
  margin-left: 70px;
  background-color: yellow;
}

.profile_photo {
  width: 300px;
  height: 390px;
  background-color: blue;
  padding: 10px 10px 10px 10px;
}

.container_1 {
  display: flex;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="container_1"></div>
  <div class="right_menu">
    <p>Моя страница</p>
    <p>Новости</p>
    <p>Сообщения</p>
    <p>Друзья</p>
    <p>Группы</p>
    <p>Фотографии</p>
    <p>Музыка</p>
    <p>Видео</p>
    <p>Игры</p>
  </div>
  <div class="profile_photo">
    <img src="https://get.wallhere.com/photo/women-model-car-legs-shorts-high-heels-road-thighs-Person-girl-beauty-leg-footwear-photo-shoot-abdomen-332459.jpg" style="width:300px; height: 300px;">
  </div>
</div>
```

А картинка под менюшкой, потому, что `div` Элемент блочный и это его естественное поведение

```css
.container,
.container_1 {
  margin: 5px;
  width: 100px;
  height: 100px;
  background: red;
}
```

```html
<div class="container"></div>
<div class="container_1"></div>
```

Comment: а я помню ты меня спрашивал откуда такие ножки ...:))

Comment: @МаксимЛенский , решил не нарушать традиции)))))

Comment: @Air Вот это ноги нашёл. Плюс за решение, а не за ножки, хотя ноги тоже хороши :)

Comment: @Alexandr_TT, ))))))))

Answer (score 0):

добавь `float:left` к `.right_menu`

https://html5book.ru/css-position/#float

Comment: Ну и зачем минусовать? Правильный ответ же. Ну почти правильный...